# Chrome reloading image when moving it from one element to another, Firefox and Internet Explorer simply *move* the image. How can I work around this?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

If I have an image on the page that I want to move from one element to another, Firefox and Internet explorer simply *moves* the image, while Chrome actually re-pings the image source for content. How can I force Chrome to not re-ping the source, but just *move* the image from one container to another?

I can confirm this by setting the image source to an Asp.NET MVC controller, and set a breakpoint to see when it's requested. Here is an example:

MVC Controller:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult ImgController()
        {
            // Set breakpoint in this controller
            Image i = Image.FromFile(@"C:\img.png");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            i.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            return new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), "Image");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
<img src="Home/ImgController" />
<div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].outerHTML;
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

When the page initially loads the breakpoint in the `ImgController` controller is hit, which is expected. But when the `setTimeout` javascript function is executed after 5 seconds, the breakpoint in `ImgController` is hit a second time **only in Chrome**. In Firefox and Internet Explorer the breakpoint is never hit because it just moves the element.

I've also tried `appendChild`, and jQuery's `.html()`, both have the same result.

How can I force Chrome to use the element it already has in the DOM instead of re-pinging the server for repeat content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a resolution, in case anybody comes across with this same problem.

I've found if I declare the image as a global javascript variable Chrome won't re-query the server. Here's an example:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
<div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.src = "Home/ImgController";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(tmpImg);
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].appendChild(tmpImg);
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoint is likely showing you the REQUEST, which will return 304 (not modified), which does not actually transmit the image a second time. You're better off looking at the browser's NETWORK panel in the debugger and looking at what's going over the wire, rather than the event in your app.

Why .NET would be making a trip to the server for a DOM event in the first place is beyond me.

Comment: My question is why does Chrome even query the server again? Other browsers don't do it, and it's not an expected behavior in my opinion.